# IBM DB2 ODBC driver returns the wrong value for the ODBC API SQLGetInfo()

Tags: db2, odbc

IBM DB2 ODBC driver returns the wrong value when the following ODBC API is called:

```
void Test()
{
   // Allocate environment handle.
   SQLHENV environmentHandle;
   SQLRETURN returnCode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &environmentHandle);

   // Set ODBC version to 3.8
   returnCode = SQLSetEnvAttr(environmentHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3_80, 0);

   // Allocate connection handle.
   SQLHDBC connectionHandle;
   returnCode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, environmentHandle, &connectionHandle);

   // Connect to the database.
   TCHAR dsn[] = _T("DSN=ODBCDB2"), connStringOut[100] = _T("");
   SQLSMALLINT connStringOutSize = 0;
   returnCode = SQLDriverConnect(connectionHandle, NULL, (SQLTCHAR *)dsn, _tcslen(dsn), (SQLTCHAR*)connStringOut, sizeof(connStringOut) / sizeof(TCHAR), &connStringOutSize, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
   // connStringOut = L"DSN=ODBCDB2;UID=<userid>;PWD=<password>;DBALIAS=TESTDB"

   // Retrieve the quote character.
   TCHAR quoteValue[15] = _T("");
   SQLSMALLINT infoValue = 0;
   returnCode = SQLGetInfo(connectionHandle, SQL_IDENTIFIER_QUOTE_CHAR, &quoteValue, sizeof(quoteValue), &infoValue);
   // quoteValue = L"03.80"
   // infoValue = 10
}
```

The API call `SQLGetInfo()` should return the quote character such as a double quote character ("), a single quote character (') etc. Instead it returns `03.80` which is incorrect. This value looks to be the ODBC driver version.

**Update:** If the parameter `SQL_OV_ODBC3_80` in `SQLSetEnvAttr()` is changed to either `SQL_OV_ODBC3` or `SQL_OV_ODBC2`, then the quote character is correct ("). Looks to be the version specific problem.

> Environment Details:
>
> - IBM DB2 v11.5.0.1077
> - IBM DB2 ODBC Driver v11.5.0.1077 (32-bit)
> - ODBC v3.8
> - VC++ (Visual Studio 2017)
> - Windows 10 64-bit

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: It works correctly for me (Win10 64bit, v11.5.0.1088), returns ".  Check you toolchain and build, and also suggest the final argument to SQLGetInfo is valid pointer, whose returned value you should check (is 1 on return in my case)

Comment: Thanks, mao! I just created a new sample app (32bit), the issue still persists. Also, for some reason the 64bit driver is failing to load.

Comment: What is the value returned via the final (fifth) parameter , as per my suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The Db2 V11.5 "sqlext.h" already has SQL_SPEC_MAJOR (3) and SQL_SPEC_MINOR ("80"), if you compiled with that version, meaning it should not be necessary to explicitly set that ODBC version in your code, as that version may be the default with V11.5 despite what the documentation suggests!

The [Db2 documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0000615.html) is inadequate because it has the unqualified remark:

> "If you set the SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION attribute to SQL_OV_ODBC3_80
>   (value 380), CLI returns "03.80""

It appears that the code does return that value even if you are enquiring about `SQL_IDENTIFIER_QUOTE_CHAR`. I can reproduce that symptom with VS2019 and V11.5 after minor code changes to initialize the TCHAR arrays correctly. That seems like undesirable behaviour to me, but only IBM can decide whether it is defective.

I suggest you open a ticket with IBM Db2 support for that specific question.

As you observed, the workaround is to compile/link with the V11.5 headers/libraries and don't explicitly set the ODBC version with SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION (i.e. omit the line of code `returnCode = SQLSetEnvAttr(environmentHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3_80, 0);` ).  In that case the `SQLGetInfo` for the quote character returns the correct value.

Comment: Thanks mao! The problem is, if the ODBC version is not set explicitly then the call `SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, environmentHandle, &connectionHandle)` returns the error `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error`.

Comment: I don't observe that behaviour if I omit explicitly setting the ODBC version, instead, the connection succeeds and I can print out the correct quote character returned by GetInfo. Something  missing from your description maybe?